# Sorting of document collection with compromising performance in SSJS

Tags: xpages, ssjs

I want to sort notesDocument collection based on any key or date in ascending order ( document creation date). Actually I need data to display in data table in **descending  order** so that user can view most recent record on the top.

Please provide me solution to sort the collection but I don't want to **compromise the performance**.

Thanks,
Qaiser

Comment: Please share some code so we can help you. Also, you usually keep the view sorted and hence the collection is always sorted. Please share some code.

Comment: Thanks for response. I am already having sorted view based on date but when I get collection using getDocumentByKey system sorts record based on creation date when I display the data in data table.

Comment: As for sample code is concerned var mName:NotesName = session.createName(@UserName()); var mView:NotesView =  database.getView("myRequests"); var mDc:NotesDocumentCollection = mView.getAllDocumentsByKey(mName.getAbbreviated , true );  if ( mDc.getCount() > 0 ) { return mDc }. same data can be used in data table.

Comment: Moreover I am also using var mQry:string = "Select Form = 'Application' "; var mDc:NotesDocumentCollection = database.search(mQry); return mDc;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qaiser,
if you want to avoid a performance hit, don't use `database.search`. It is the equivalent of a full table scan without an index. Bad idea.

The better way: create a view that has all the columns you need and is sorted the way you need it. So your first column would be the field with the user name, categorize it, then a column with the date, sorted.

Then you can use a ViewNavigator which is the fastest construct in Domino.

Comment: I will add just a hint: when you want to sort based on different attributes (key, date...) use more views sorted the way you want. More views may cause some performance issues, but it is the best option to get your searches fast.